# Responsive navigation inside a fixed width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I am using a responsive navigation solution called Naver (http://formstone.it/components/Naver) for my websites. However, I am running into issues when I use the responsive navigation in a fixed width (like a grid for example). The responsive navigation takes the width of it's parent element and doesn't show at 100% width.

Here are two examples, one with the navigation inside of a grid and one just floated to the right:

- http://jsfiddle.net/9FCq2/11/
- http://jsfiddle.net/9FCq2/10/

**Note:** I have a couple of external resources in each of those fiddles.

I'm wondering how I can somehow adjust my CSS or JavaScript to make my responsive dropdown show at 100% when clicked on, no matter what the width of the parent element.

**HTML**

```
<div class="clearfix">
    <div class="float-left">
        <a href="http://concisecss.com">
                <img src="http://concisecss.com/images/logo.svg" alt="Concise Logo" width="150" />
            </a>
    </div>

    <div class="float-right">
        <nav class="nav-responsive">
            <ul class="list-inline list-unstyled">
                <li><a href="">Welcome</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="">Why Concise</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="">Get Started</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="">Documentation</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="">Add-Ons</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.naver .naver-handle {
    color: inherit;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    line-height: 1;
    text-align: right;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    -o-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
.naver .naver-wrapper {
    height: auto;
}
.naver.enabled .naver-handle {
    display: block;
}
.naver.enabled .naver-wrapper {
    height: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.naver.enabled .naver-wrapper ul li {
    display: block;
    padding: 8px;
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
}
.naver.enabled .naver-wrapper ul li:hover {
    background: #f9f9f9;
}
.nav-responsive.naver .naver-handle:after {
    content:"\f0c9";
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    text-align: right;
}
```

Naver jQuery library: http://formstone.it/components/Naver/jquery.fs.naver.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give the nav and it's top container `width` of `100%`. By doing this you guarantee that both will take `100%` of your screen's width (or whatever is the container both are in)

for your first jsfiddle use `.naver-wrapper{width:100%;}` because `naver-wrapper` is the top parent for your navigation. [Check here](http://jsfiddle.net/9FCq2/13/)

while in your second example you have to give both the navigation and the top container (parent) `width:100%` [Check here](http://jsfiddle.net/9FCq2/14/)

```
.naver-wrapper{width:100%;}
.float-right{width:100%;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Below CSS. I hope this is useful for you:

**CSS**

```
.naver.enabled .naver-wrapper{
overflow: hidden;  position: absolute; left: 0px; width: 100%; }
```